# npm install requires sudo, sudo npm install returns command not found Ubuntu (using nvm)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, npm, sudo

i'm fairly new to deving and I think I have sudo npm installed -g resulting in a permissions issue. I had some help, and we used rm -Rf on all instances of node files node_modules and npm files. It fixed the problem I had ( which was running learnyounode commands globally ) however my npm install is not working anymore (requiring sudo) and when I sudo npm install it returns sudo: npm: command not found

this is the error that is returned when I npm install

`npm WARN deprecated gulp-rimraf@0.1.1: Use npmjs.org/del instead, see https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md
npm WARN deprecated sequelize@2.0.5: critical security fix in v3.0.0
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/dmeow/.npm/bluebird/2.9.34'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/dmeow/.npm/bluebird/2.9.34']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/dmeow/.npm/bluebird/2.9.34' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/dmeow/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/node" "/home/dmeow/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/dmeow/GG/Airship
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/dmeow/.npm/bluebird/2.9.34
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/dmeow/.npm/bluebird/2.9.34'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dmeow/GG/Airship/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Can anyone offer some help please, with very detailed instructions. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92 discusses why `sudo` should never be used with `npm`. It addresses the security risk, and the problem of the forced install not belonging to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your executable got messed up.

Uninstall

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove npm
```

reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

This fixed that issue when I had it.